# Django can't login after sign up using custom model

Tags: django, django-models

So i create a custom model with AbstractUser:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=False, null=False) # Validators should be a list
    is_shop = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "scrape_customuser"
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: 
            self.set_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and a sign up form

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']
```

my login logic:

```
def shop_user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_shop = True
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            referring_url = request.POST.get('next', None)
                if  referring_url:
                    return redirect(referring_url)
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'shop_user_signup.html', {'form': form})
```

The user got created in the database with password got hash to something like this `pbkdf2_sha256$600000$TvRyCcSY6eMhnV1i1urh93$aKLqPBrcma5KsuS469crJtS93UI0h+7pduJXeW6ukAU=`, `is_active=1` and somehow the last login is `2023-11-23 15:49:22.581983` even though the redirect didn't show username when i have

```
<li class="nav-item">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">{{user.username}} | Logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

When i try to login in the login page i got the error `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.` And the admin account can login normally.

Comment: Don't set the password in the `save` method it will hash the password a *second* time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't* set the password in the model. This will hash the password a *second* time: once by the form, and once by the model. Indeed, if we look at the `BaseUserCreationForm`, [we see <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4eb9c3d90aff55182151b6be0122f7d0b28832fd/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L147-L154):

> ```
> def save(self, commit=True):
>     user = super().save(commit=False)
>     user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
>     if commit:
>         user.save()
>         if hasattr(self, "save_m2m"):
>             self.save_m2m()
>     return user
> ```

So omit rehashing it a second time:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.",
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=False, null=False
    )  # Validators should be a list
    is_shop = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'scrape_customuser'

    # no override
```

You can simplify the view to:

```
def shop_user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.is_shop = True
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            referring_url = request.POST.get('next', None)
                if  referring_url:
                    return redirect(referring_url)
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'shop_user_signup.html', {'form': form})
```

and in the template, check:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: now a new problem have arrive. create admin using `py manage.py createsuperuser` do successfully create account with `is_superuser=1`, `is_staff=1`, `is_active=1` and `last_login=NULL` but i can't login the admin page, the error message still the same

Comment: @Dung8466: did you define a custom user manager?

Comment: no, but i do add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'scrape.CustomUser'` to settings.py